# Desirability approach to multiple optimization: drawbacks and alternatives

Tags: experiment-design, optimization

When fitting some relations $y_j=f_j(x_1, \ldots, x_p)+\epsilon_j$ between a multivariate response $y=(y_1, ..., y_k)$ and covariates $x_i$, a common problem is to determine for which values of the covariates $x_i$ the responses $y_j$, or the model functions $f_j$, attains an optimum. This problem is classical in the literature about "response surface" models.  Of course it is not possible in general to find a simultaneous optimum, that is, a solution $(x_1, \ldots, x_p)$ for which *every* function $f_j$ attains its optimum.

Based on experimental data the [desirability approach](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/INFOVIS/PAPER178.PDF) to this problem consists in:

- define some kind of "average" response $z=d_1(y_1)\cdots d_k(y_k)$, fit an univariate model $z=g(x_1, \ldots, x_p)+\epsilon$ and optimize the univariate fitted function $\hat g$;
- or firstly fit $p$ univariate regression models $y_j=\hat f_j(x_1, \ldots, x_p) + \epsilon_j$, $j=1,\ldots,p$, and then seek values of the covariates $x_i$ for which the functions $\hat f_j$ attain some kind of "simultaneous" optimum by defining a univariate "average" fitted model $\prod d_j(\hat f_j)$ and finally find its optimum.

I am not attracted by this approach for the following reasons:

- The choice of the "desirability functions" $d_j$ seems too delicate and arbitrary to me. Even with strong prior knowledge and clear objectives (a rare practical situation). I would not be suprised that many users try numerous choices *a posteriori* and finally choose the one that suits them best (hence their choice is data-dependent)
- I don't know whether there exists an appealing way to quantify the uncertainty about the solution provided by the desirability approach (even when assuming the desirability functions $d_j$ are the good ones I don't know whether it is possible to obtain some kind of confidence interval about the solution)
- This approach doesn't take into account the correlation between the univariate responses $y_j$

I would be interested in discussing these points and any other comments. Moreover I am interested in the alternatives to the desirability approach. Peterson and other authors (see for instance [this powerpoint presentation and references given therein](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=peterson%20bayesian%20optimization&source=web&cd=10&cad=rja&ved=0CHkQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stat.colostate.edu%2Fgraybillconference2008%2FPresentations%2FPETERSON_Peterson%2520A%2520Bayesian%2520Approach%2520to%2520the%2520ICH%2520Q8%2520Design%2520Space.ppt&ei=PKBHUIeiEamj0QXn5oGoCg&usg=AFQjCNFpBn-f9VKLH_AfueskFiWQBrDetA)) proposed a more appealing approach: they fit a Bayesian multivariate linear model and then they optimize the posterior predictive probability that the multivariate response $y$ belongs to some prespecified set $A$. There's no need to be Bayesian for this approach: this probability can also be considered as an estimate of $\Pr(y \in A)$ and we can also provide a confidence interval about the optimized probability $\Pr(y \in A)$. The user must choose $A$ but with clear objectives this choice is not as arbitrary as the choice of the desirability functions $d_j$ (for instance we want a temperature to be higher than $20$, a concentration between $2$ and $4$...), and it well defined *a priori*. Do you know other alternatives to this multiple optimization problem ?

**EDIT 06/09/2012:** The introduction of [this paper by Peterson & al](http://web.it.nctu.edu.tw/~qtqm/qtqmpapers/2009V6N4/2009V6N4_F1.pdf) is an excellent discussion about the present topic.